# Ошибки перевода на странице "очередь проверок"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Справа на странице "очередь проверок" можно увидеть следующий блок, в котором, как я полагаю, есть несколько ошибок.

[image: Ошибка перевода]

Явную ошибку выделил. Также думаю, что стоит в списке писать:

- Выполняйте оценку новых сообщений
- Голосуйте за закрытие или повторное открытие вопросов
- Проверяйте предложенные правки

Comment: Поправил, где мог в transifex, создал issue.