# Как часто обновлённые переводы с transifex переносятся на сайт?

Tags: поддержка, локализация

На странице [очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review) фраза:

> Stack Overflow is moderated by you.

переводится как:

> Stack Overflow на русском модерированные Вами.

Что лучше перевести как:

> Stack Overflow на русском модерируется вами.

[как это в transifex сейчас переведено](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265363?q=moderated%20by%20you), предложено в [Ошибки перевода на странице "очередь проверок"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba) 4 мая 2015.

На сайте до сих пор показан старый (неправильный) перевод.

Comment: База строк обновляется вручную через специальный интерфейс. Обновления попадают на сайт в случае сборки движка (происходит несколько раз в день).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: то есть перевод с transifex больше не используется? (не могу понять "несколько раз в день" и отсутствие исправления на живом сайте, которое доступно уже 20 дней в transifex)

Comment: Transifex используем. _Путь строк_. 1) Новые строки генерируются в движке. 2) Строки загружаются на Transifex. 3) Строки переводятся. 4) Строки отмечаются проверенными (кнопка Review). 5) Проверенные строки вручную загружаются из Transifex в движок (два клика на сайте). 6) Создаем новую сборку движка. Многие строки не отмечены как проверенные, и это вина компании, а не сообщества (к сожалению, иногда упускаю что-то из виду).

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovksy [Отправьте туда в конвейер те 500 строк из диапазона, что я перевел с машинного, полтора месяц уже болтаются, жалко что пропадает.] (https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/viewstrings/#ru/english/40264472?user=igumnov&reviewed=no)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: А как можно помочь?

Comment: @VladD Буду рад повысить ваш статус на Transifex до редактора (который reviewer)!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: С удовольствием!

Comment: @VladD Здорово! Готово.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Есть ли где-то очередь/список актуальных заданий по переводу? Или можно просто смотреть багрепорты в Мете?

Comment: @VladD Каких-либо списков нет. Было бы здорово обратить внимание на ошибки указанные на Мете. Я, в свою очередь, пройдусь по остальным строкам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: а как часто шаг 5) выполняется? Например, я вижу, [reviewed перевод на transifex для Related (два дня назад)](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265231?q=related), но на самом сайте я до сих пор вижу Связанный-Связанные, то есть перевод не используется.  [я не вижу других "Related" слов, которые в заголовок бы шли](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262889?q=related)

Comment: @jfs Обычно, я обновляю базу если я или кто-либо другой выставляет задаче, связанной с переводом строк, [meta-tag:status-completed], а также, если кто-то напишет об необходимости обновить строки в чате.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не могу найти информацию о том, как присоединиться к процессу локализации. Пните меня в правильном направлении, пожалуйста.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev На данный момент вся информация о переводе доступна на [главной странице справочного центра](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). В ближайшее время перенесу на Мету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переводы, сделанные в Transifex, должны быть утверждены модератором переводов (в последнее время, обычно [это я](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/176217)), после чего сотрудник Stack Overflow (обычно это [Николас](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky)) может «дернуть» специальный рычаг переноса, о чём ранее его просили в чате, теперь - по мере мониторинга им тем на Мете или каким-то другим признакам (лучше уточнить непосредственно). Далее нужно дождаться пересборки движка сайта (версия сборки указана внизу справа на каждой странице), которая может быть инициирована разработчиком Stack Overflow (это уже не Николас), и только после этого новые переводы строк будут видны всем посетителям. Если цепочка этих действий нарушена, то переводов не будет до выполнения упомянутых условий в правильном порядке.

Если же говорить исключительно об изменении уже переведённых строк, то учитывая, что в transifex много строк, которые реально ещё не используются, ревью делается в основном по требованию. На основании вопроса на Мете или сообщения в чате (маловероятно). То есть когда есть реальные предпосылки к изменению тех или иных строк.