# Alexolut – новый корректор на Transifex!

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, вехи

Поздравляем участника [@alexolut](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/)! По результатам [его огромного вклада](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A176217+%5B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D) в улучшение перевода сайта, коллегия текущих переводчиков ([@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/), [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/)), с согласия @alexolut, назначила его корректором (то есть модератором переводов). Таким образом, @alexolut имеет доступ к правке и утверждению любых строк на Transifex.

Большое спасибо за улучшение перевода! Правильно подобранные строки в интерфейсе пользователя имеют огромное значение для удобства использования сайта.

<sub>Если вы хотите принять участие в переводе, пожалуйста, начните с вопроса на Мете: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/).</sub>

Comment: Оу... прямо-таки личная тема! Спасибо за доверие! Ограничусь комментарием тут. P.S. Избегайте комментариев вида "Спасибо" и "У меня тоже" :)

Comment: Давно предлагал. А говорили что нельзя :) Поздравляю, @alexolut!

Comment: Надеюсь, традиция создания личных тем будет продолжена. Не то тот же VladD не так давно наотвечал на шестизначную репутацию, — выдающееся достижение для Stack Overflow на русском, — а на Мете об этом ни слова. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexolut поздравляю!

Comment: @alexolut мои поздравления. Slowpoke.jpg

Comment: @Suvitruf уже забыл совсем об этом :)

Comment: @alexolut интернет всё помнит)