# Убрать перевод UTC в попапе достижения

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, дизайн

Я и так знаю, что это "УНИВЕРСАЛЬНОЕ ГЛОБАЛЬНОЕ ВРЕМЯ". Из-за этого кнопки привилегии и знаки съехали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, до меня только сейчас дошло, о чём говорится в этом вопросе. Ну скриншоты же добавлять надо...

Comment: @Qwertiy Я улучшил название вопроса.

Comment: А мне одному интересно, почему время - это достижение?)

Comment: @Qwertiy Потратить время это достижение

Answer (score 3):

В оригинале там [`UTC TIME`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266280?key=5ff753788fdebefcfe49b9c81960d604), которое в transifex задано вовсе строчными буквами и есть ещё вариант просто [`UTC`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263446?key=9234324ddf6b4176b57d803a925b7961).

Обе эти строки сейчас переводятся как

> универсальное глобальное время

Предлагаю `utc time` перевести как

> Время по UTC

А UTC оставить как есть в оригинале, т.е.

> UTC

Comment: Тавтология "UTC TIME"

Comment: @Alex78191 посмотрите сами на enSO. Я не могу менять оригинальные строки, только переводные :)

Comment: В смысле вы не можете? Вы не админ. Я про enSO сказал

Comment: Мне кажется, что вариант "Время UTC" (без предлога) читается лучше.

Comment: @Alex78191 [я что-то среднее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4066/alexolut-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-transifex) :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov так не говорят

Comment: В смысле "вариант просто `UTC`."? Вы же написали переменная `UTC TIME` используется. Можно в эту переменную записать текст "UTC".

Answer (score 3):

Волевым решением заинтересованных участников по итогам обсуждения в чате выбрали перевод «Время UTC». Будет доступно в следующей сборке.

Comment: По Google Trends выбирали?