# Переименовать метку [ipython-notebook] в [jupyter-notebook]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, переименование-метки

Проект IPython Notebook был [переименован в Jupyter Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook). Думаю, стоит переименовать соответствующую метку [ipython-notebook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/ipython-notebook) в [jupyter-notebook](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/jupyter-notebook).

Comment: Вот переименуют [tag:javascript] в [tag:java], тоже синоним добавим.

Comment: @alexolut, ну, здесь по сути проект отпочковался от проекта IPython и кроме Python стал поддерживать Julia и R (отсюда название - Ju-Pyt-e-R), поэтому и переименовали. javascript в java (или наоборот) вряд ли переименуют)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tag Synonym ipython-notebook -> jupyter-notebook was approved!

Comment: Где эти переводчики??? Почему опять сообщение не локализовано??? @alexolut???!

Comment: @Grundy это вообще что-то вроде логов

Comment: @Grundy [не переводчик!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/176217). Да и нет такого в transifex.

Comment: @alexolut, то есть **даже** не переводчик?

Comment: @Grundy никому не нужен!