# Довыборы модератора

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация, нытьё

В свете всех последних событий, хотелось бы предложить довыбрать одного модератора, в обязанности которого будет входить, преимущественно, работа с комьюнити:

1. Общение с пользователями.
2. Перевод своевременный постов/обсуждений с en меты.
3. Публикация там вопросов/ответов от имени ru SO.
4. и т.д.

Да, сейчас модераторы справляются именно по части модерирования.

Да, Николас говорил, что довыборы не планируются.

Но в текущей ситуации многое указывает на то, что нам такой человек нужен. Текущие модераторы не особо горят желанием заниматься с комьюнити, а те, кому приходится это делать, явно не в восторге от этого.

Comment: + модерация чата (?)

Comment: @АндрейNOP овнерство. Часть 2.

Comment: @alexolut новый виток )

Comment: @alexolut, ну теперь с настоящим ромбом

Comment: Будьте осторожны в своих желаниях. А что я пойду и выставлю свою кандидатуру. 

Comment: Что-то я не вижу пункта ведение группы в ВК :) Да и твиттер можно снова раскурить. А если серьёзно, то, что-то всё равно много пунктов. Один перевод постов с англометы многого стоит. Выполнять всё это можно только за зарплату. Ну, или это должны быть разные люди. Много разных людей.

Comment: Идея хорошая, вот только проблема в том, что довыбрать кого-то конкретного, что будет именно работать с community, достаточно сложно. мы же не можем фильтровать кандидатов. Возьмут и выберут Athari - у него очков много, и бан прошел, а он возьмет и опять на пол года пропадет - чем это поможет в работе с community? :)

Comment: @alexolut VK пока на мне висит. Но времени нет совсем )=

Comment: @PashaPash пропадёт, выберем нового?

Comment: @Suvitruf намылить, смыть, повторить?

Comment: @PashaPash ну а как иначе? Можно, конечно, кого-то на эту должность поставить номинально, без лычек. Но это совсем не то будет, по-моему.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну дык писать что выбираем именно для таких целей. А не понравится — можно и перевыбрать, это, вроде, бесплатно для Компании?

Comment: @PashaPash вот потому и надо периодическую аттестацию проводить и гнать за непосещаемость. А то выдали ромб и крутись как хочешь.

Comment: Поясните, а для чего этому особому выбранному человеку нужно иметь привелегии модераторства? Можно и сейчас, без "лычек" общаться, переводить и постить (и звать проголосовать на enSO), и т.д.

Comment: @Kromster так работает психология. Я много работал с разными комьюнити. Люди обычно загораются идеей, но в среднем через месяц забивают на это дело, особенно, если их деятельность никак не выделяет их среди остального комьюнити. А статус модератора будет оказывать психологическое давление, чтоб не забросил.

Comment: @alexolut, `Что-то я не вижу пункта ведение группы в ВК` — и [youtube-канала](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwwnMkw2Lok36TtjEVd7uqQ) заодно.

Comment: Bharata хорошую правку предложил. Зря отклонили.

Comment: @Kromster не считаю замену слова "комьюнити" на "сообщество" важной правкой.

Comment: @Kromster авторский стиль потерялся ;D

Answer (score 8):

Такой человек нам нужен. Он смог бы организовать более плотный контакт между SE и ruSO. Но где ж его взять и какие инструменты ему выдать для работы?

Для чего этому особому выбранному человеку нужно иметь привелегии модераторства? Не вижу, каким образом этот человек, привлеченный лычками "модератора", при этом не будет пользоваться модераторскими инструментами, но будет замотивирован делать то, для чего "лычки" ему не нужны. При том, что возможность модераторства на него будет действовать лишь отвлекающе.

Можно и сейчас, без "лычек" общаться, переводить и постить (и звать проголосовать на enSO за важные вещи), и т.д. Скорее человек должен быть изначально мотивирован, проявить себя в перечисленных вещах, и тогда сообщество (и КМ) могут обсудить как им поддержать его работу, в т.ч. уважением, признанием, доступом к нужным для его работы инструментам (каким кстати?), и прочими плюшками из тех, что есть в рапоряжении у компании и у сообщества.

А просто так заманивать людей "лычками" модератора на работу, в которой им модерировать будет не положено - считаю бред.

P.S. У меня был опыт такого получения "модерирования за работу для коммьюнити". Ничего толкового это мне не дало, а лишь отвлекало на мелочи и локальные "драмы".

---

Недавно попался на глаза пример подобного "роста" в прошлом: [Alexolut – новый корректор на Transifex!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4066)

Comment: Ромб нужен, как минимум, для посещения специального чата и голоса в нем