# Необходимы довыборы модераторов

Tags: предложение, модерация

Дорогие коллеги, у нас назрела проблема.

Как мы все знаем, роль модераторов в нашем сообществе **не сводится к проверке очередей закрытия вопросов**. Модераторы у нас определяют внутреннюю политику, решают конфликтные ситуации, активно поддерживают ту или иную точку зрения, участвуют в общественной жизни, модерируют чат. При этом модераторы имеют реальную силу, так как могут легко исключить носителей того или иного мнения из обсуждения, забанив их.

Таким образом, говорить о том, что модераторы у нас лишь занимаются мелкой проверкой контента, было бы близоруко и не отвечало бы сложившимся фактам. Активный модератор у нас является серьёзной общественной фигурой, в отличие от обычного участника.

Назревшая проблема состоит в том, что у нас остался лишь один активный в общественной жизни модератор (не буду называть имена, но мы все прекрасно знаем, кто это). Я не обвиняю остальных модераторов, у них есть свои жизненные обстоятельства и своя жизнь в оффлайне. Но нам нужны ещё модераторы из числа людей, которые (а) имеют время на онлайн, и (б) небезразличны к проблемам сообщества.

Одного человека для решения периодически возникающих драм недостаточно! Тем более, что он имеет «сложные» отношения с некоторыми участниками, и не может таким образом защищать интересы этих участников перед администрацией. Один модератор бывает на сайте не всегда, и слишком часто находится в оппозиции к активной части сообщества. Это означает, что он не представляет в реальности всё сообщество, а лишь небольшую её часть.

Очевидно, необходимо, чтобы большая часть сообщества также имела свой голос и была представлена в модераторском составе. Поэтому нам нужны новые модераторы, и я надеюсь, что распределение мнений и предпочтений среди них будет намного ближе к распределению мнений и предпочтений в нашем сообществе.

Что нужно делать? Я призываю организовать **довыборы модераторов**! Для того, чтобы погасить конфликты, нам нужны, по моему мнению, выдержанные, социально компетентные модераторы, понимающие проблемы сообщества, и считающие своей обязанностью отчитываться перед своими избирателями. Это поможет улучшить атмосферу, и улучшит жизнь нашего сообщества.

---

Ответы на возникшие вопросы:

- *Зачем нужен именно модератор, ведь общественной жизнью может заниматься кто угодно?* — Нет, это не так, без модераторского ромба ничего существенного сделать невозможно. Например, решить [проблемы, высказанные сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/10105), простые участники не могут, а текущий модераторский состав их не решает. Кроме того, забанить/разбанить участника может лишь модератор, а бан у нас, как это не смешно, ключевой инструмент разрешения конфликтов.
- *Зачем выбирать модератора, несогласного с администрацией, если она может снять его по своему желанию без учёта мнения сообщества?* — Это не так страшно. Снятый один модератор вызовет довыборы, на которых придёт другой. Если администрация, теоретически, будет постоянно по надуманным причинам снимать модераторов, этот вопрос можно будет поднять на Meta.SE, чтобы прекратить такую практику.
- *Новоизбранный модератор может и отказаться решать проблемы сообщества, игнорирую свои предвыборные обещания* — Да, формально невозможно заставить выполнять свои предвыборные обещания. Очень бы хотелось иметь механизм отзыва модератора, который нарушает свои обещания, и вообще ввести механизм ответственности избранных перед избирателями. Я надеюсь, что мы выберем таких модераторов, которые, руководствуясь [данными подсайтам свободами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7692/10105), смогут разработать и воплотить нужный механизм.
- *Единственная проблема — драмы в чате, а их можно решить и по-другому* — Нет, драмы в чате — лишь верхушка айсберга. Драмы в чате возникают из-за того, что другие, более серьёзные проблемы игнорируются администрацией и модсоставом, и являются следствием бессилия небезразличных участников в решении этих проблем. Баны не решат проблему, а лишь подавят её высказывание. Мы же не хотим занять страусову позицию, просто заткнув рот тем, кто говорит о проблемах?
- *Нет никакого способа выбрать «нужного» человека. Нет способа выбрать именно «модератора чата» или «разруливателя драм».* — Я надеюсь на достаточную мудрость сообщества, которая позволит выбрать небезразличных модераторов. А уж они смогут организовать процесс «разруливания драм» и продавить его через косность управляющих структур. В конце-концов, мы как сообщество [можем менять правила](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7692/10105), чтобы наш подсайт был лучше.
- *Если есть проблемы на основном сайте — то их стоит обсудить на Мете, а не пытаться выбрать человека, который придет и решит их за нас. Модераторы — исполнители решений на Мете.* — Теоретически да, практически не работает. Текущий модсостав не решил ни одну из [упомянутых здесь проблем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/10105), и никак даже не отреагировал на Мете ответным постом (несколько комментариев одного из модераторов я не считаю). Очень часто вместо попыток решения проблем модераторами я припоминаю лишь казуиситику наподобие «а сколько голосов нужно?» или там «решения голосованием на Мете не имеют силы».

---

Дополнительная тема, которую я хотел бы поднять, такова. К сожалению, в недавних конфликтах администрация пошла по пути бана недовольных участников. Таким образом, мы оказались в ситуации, когда большая часть активных, неравнодушных участников, несогласных с администрацией, побывала в бане, и, таким образом, не может по формальным критериям участвовать в выборах. Это приведёт к тому, что выбраны будут либо «лояльные» участники, не принимающие критическую точку зрения, либо безразличные, которым не интересны проблемы сообщества.

Но в модераторском составе должны быть представлены различные точки зрения! Что толку в модераторах, которые не защищают своих избирателей? Значит, точка зрения недовольной части сообщества должна быть представлена в модераторском составе!

Поэтому я призываю администрацию приостановить действие правила о недопущении участников, бывших в бане, к выборам. Это ключевой момент, без которого выборы будут фарсом.

---

Заметьте, это уже не первый пост с призывом к довыборам. Нет, этот вопрос — не дубликат, ситуация с того времени сильно поменялась.

Comment: С текущей системой выборов вы вряд ли "своего" получите в составе модераторов. Если будут довыборы то победит кто-нибудь типо Грунди, если вы сами избираться не планируете, конечно (:

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я буду активно агитировать за «своих». (Примечание для _сам знает кого_: свои — это те, кто, по моему мнению, может улучшить сайт.)

Comment: Текущие модераторы и Николас, я всё ещё верю, не жаждут уничтожения сайта.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Возможно, так оно и есть. Но видение того, что нужно делать, у разных групп разное.

Comment: @VladD сейчас у нас одна действительно актуальная проблема - регулярные драмы в чате. Текущее решение по драмам в чате - выносить их в отдельную комнату. Без удаления и банов, но без флуда в общих комнатах. Предлагаю попробовать его, вдруг его будет достаточно?

Comment: @PashaPash: Я считаю, что драмы — это не проблема, а следствие. Запрятав симптомы подальшем, проблему не решить.

Comment: @VladD если чат вообще удалят/закроют, то какая проблема останется? В смысле, весной было недопонимание границ влияния. Все уяснили, что сообщество может влиять на вопросы по контенту и т.п, а не на вопросы администрации. А сейчас? Если бы чата вообще не было, то проблема бы была?

Comment: @VladD Насчет довыборов - нет никакого способа выбрать "нужного" человека. Нет способа выбрать именно "модератора чата" или "разруливателя драм". Если проблемы (и баны за флуд, и флуд за баны) проявляются прежде всего в чате - то стоит попробовать решить их в чате. Если есть проблемы на основном сайте - то их стоит обсудить на мете, а не пытаться выбрать человека, который придет и решит их за нас. Модераторы - исполнители решений на мете. А не "решающие за сообщество".

Comment: @PashaPash: Есть, этот метод называется «выборы».

Comment: @PashaPash: Решать проблемы в чате, пока там модератор активно этому сопротивляется — нонсенс.

Comment: @VladD не вижу сопротивления решению проблем в чате. в главной комнате попросили не флудить. и все. проблемы обсуждать можно (и нужно). держась при этом в рамках СoС, ес-но.

Comment: @PashaPash: Вы уходите в оффтопик. Обсучдение модерации чата — не в этом вопросе. Иначе забаню.

Comment: «*выбраны будут либо «лояльные» участники, не принимающие критическую точку зрения, либо безразличные, которым не интересны проблемы сообщества.*» — звучит крайне нелогично, да же по «Д'артаньяновски», мол, «если не выберем Василия, все пропало, никто больше не справится с этой ношей, которую нести сможет только Василий. И никто более! Даешь выборы, даешь Василия! Без него выборы не выборы». То есть вы хотите выборы или выбрать Василия? Это разные вещи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните мысль «у нас остался лишь один активный в общественной жизни модератор». Подскажите, куда смотреть, чтобы это стало ясно всем? На какие цифры?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky посмотрите на активность в чате, например. Или по специфическим меткам на Мете. Я думаю, должно быть не сложно выяснить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky публично из модов только PP и Nofate иногда выступают. Поэтому, даже если остальные модераторы активны и принимают участие в обсуждениях, то сообщество этого не видит.

Comment: @alexolut  Пожалуйста, попробуйте посмотреть на ответы и вопросы модераторов на Мете за последние 6 месяцев. Вы увидите, что у всех модераторов примерно ода и та же активность, причем, вполне хорошая.

Comment: @Suvitruf два из "нечастых" модераторов выбраны на последних выборах, и они вполне активны. Как вы предлагаете гарантировать, что на новых выбора будут выбраны именно те, то будет попадать под требования из вопроса?

Comment: Уважаемая администрация, прочитайте ещё раз вопрос. Я не об ответах на Мете, а об участии в общественной жизни

Comment: @VladD Пожалуйста, поясните понятие «общественная жизнь». Что оно в себя включает?

Comment: кстати, может быть это дубликат https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7644/ ?

Comment: @PashaPash возможно, если бы там было решение. Закрыв текущий вопрос как дубль, не решится сам вопрос то. Возможно кому-то из модераторов общую точку зрения стоит опубликовать или там, или тут. Если можете статистику по модерке приложить и по тревогам, то ещё лучше.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Хорошая погода, не правда ли? Прекрасных вам выходных.

Comment: @VladD не уверен, что вот такая правка вопроса - хорошая идея. Возможно, такие вещи стоит отдельным ответом публиковать?

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ответы на ответы выглядели бы глуповато. SO не рассчитан на дискуссии, печально.

Comment: @VladD просто в текущей ситуации те, кто уже видел вопрос, вряд ли обратят внимания на правки.

Comment: Это да, но хоть вновь пришедшие участники увидят. И я  напишу комментарии под ответами

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Довыборы модератора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7644/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос в корне уязвим. Вы хотите нового модератора, для немодераторских задач.

На поверхности, вы говорите, что хотите еще 1 модератора, но не говорите чем не хватает действующих. При этом, вы почему-то уверены, что довыборы должны принести ruSO не просто модератора, а особого модератора, занимающегося общественной жизнью и лояльного к группе в которую вы входите (а лучше поддерживающего её). А если не принесут, как вы отреагируете, предложите довыбрать еще? Так давайте отшелушим обертку, и вы скажете, что ruSO, по вашему мнению, нужен не просто еще 1 модератор, а определенный модератор, с определенными целями, так?

---

> у нас остался лишь один активный в общественной жизни модератор

Для общественной жизни никаких должностей не надо. Берете и участвуете во всем в чем хотите.

> Одного человека для решения периодически возникающих драм недостаточно! Тем более, что он имеет «сложные» отношения с некоторыми участниками, и не может таким образом защищать интересы этих участников перед администрацией.

Наличие двух модераторов имеющих «сложные» отношения не только с участниками, но и друг с другом никак не поможет снижению количеств и сил драм.

> Я призываю организовать довыборы модераторов с тем, чтобы разрушающие сообщество драмы не игнорировались и не решались наиболее разрушительным для сообщества методом — баном недовольных.

А как по вашему новый модератор должен будет решать драмы? Если блокировать "плохо", то ему останется действовать только словами. А для слов модератором быть не обязательно.

То есть аргументация в вопросе неясна. Для чего конкретно нужен новый модератор, с чем не справляются текущие? Вы хотите получить своего сторонника с ромбом чтобы его не могли забанить? Но его могут забанить за то же за что банят и обычных участников точно так же.

---

В моем понимании, вы хотите представителя с ромбом для группы в которую вы входите, чтобы его носитель как-то представлял интересы вашей группы. Только непонятно зачем же вашей группе носитель ромба? Давайте вы попробуете написать список того что вы хотите что бы делалось, а рядом с каждым пунктом отметите, нужен ли для этого ромб. У меня большое подозрение, что ромб там будет нигде не нужен.

Если уж вы считаете, что модераторов не хватает, то приводите, пожалуйста, релевантные данные на тему "Обязанности модераторов и процент их выполнения". Может быть на сайте или в чате на тревоги слишком долго реагируют?

Comment: В чате на тревоги плохо реагируют в принципе, не только модераторы. Иначе к нам забугорние бы не заходили.

Comment: Разрешение конфликтов - не модераторская задача? Я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но кажется для выписки бана модераторам требуется кворум. А стало быть чем больше различных взглядов, тем выше вероятность того, что ситуация с участником будет рассмотрена качественнее. Любой, голосующий на выборах модератора хочет получить сторонника. Ну а требовать "релевантные" данные у участника, которому негде их взять - это довольно странно (хотя и практикуется тут). Хотя флаги на сайте порой действительно висят достаточно долго. Тревоги же в чате рассматривать не актуально, они общие почти на всю сеть.

Comment: @Suvitruf насколько мне известно, в чате два типа тревог, и какой-то из них, на который приходят иностранцы, гремит на всю сеть SE и приходят ровно те кто в эту секунду был онлайн.

Comment: @Kromster хм. Это через какую кнопку?

Comment: @alexolut подскажите, откуда у вас информация про кворум для бана? А также, если вы утверждаете, что рядовой участник не может получить метрики исполнения модераторами своих обязанностей, то как как он может утверждать, что искомое исполнение стало выше или ниже и что нужны еще модераторы?

Comment: @Kromster участники по косвенным метрикам только могут: долго тревоги висят, спам висит и т.п. Я уже просил не раз хотя бы раз в месяц отчёта от модераторов. Но не был услышан.

Comment: @Suvitruf о том и речь. ТС хочет непонятно чего - толи нового модератора (не поясняя чем старые не справляются с модерированием), толи ромба для занятий "общественной жизнью" (а ромб для этого не нужен).

Comment: Возможно, про кворум я слышал в чате, надо уточнить у мод.состава. Но учитывая серьёзность такого действия как бан, логично предположить, что он должен выписываться не единоличным решением в порыве гнева или ещё на каких-то личных основаниях. ТС говорит о решении проблемы "драм", а не об обработке каких-то единичных флагов, именно открытых разговоров от модераторов по этой части не так много. Потому и обозначил "релевантность" в кавычках, ибо для текущей проблемы эти данные совсем не релевантны.

Comment: @Kromster: Простите, а вы читали вопрос? Я не прошу себе ромб, я призываю к выборам. На которых, как я надеюсь, будет избран модератор, не защищающий во всём администрацию.

Comment: @VladD ответ получился слишком длинным для комментария. Внес его в вопрос.

Comment: @Kromster по поводу вашей недавней правки. Я про это в своём ответе писал, но, к сожалению, он был удалён. Повторять весь текст не буду, но, если кратко, модераторы прислушиваются больше к другим модераторам, нежели к обычным пользователям, так психология работает. Точно также, как вы будете прислушиваться больше к другим сотрудникам в компанию, чем к пользователям вашего продукта. По поводу "конкретного модератора" не совсем так. Хочется модератора с альтернативными взглядами. Просто Кролик имеет большую репутацию и, в случае выдвижения, шансы победить у него выше.

Comment: @Kromster: Я говорю, для чего нужен модератор, прочитайте всё же ответ. Специально для вас добавил ещё подробностей.

Answer (score 5):

У меня нет уверенности, что довыборы в модераторский состав даже с возможностью участвовать в этих выборах участникам, побывавшим за последний год в бане, что-то изменят.

Последнее предложение [модераторского соглашения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) не обязывает компанию (а стало быть и сотрудников в её лице) озвучивать (или вовсе иметь) какие бы то ни было причины для снятия выбранного демократическим путём модератора с должности. А стало быть любой косой взгляд в сторону линии партии может быть чреват потерей ромба. В такой ситуации даже альтернативно настроенный модератор будет вынужден поменять свою точку зрения (или просто замолчать). Мы уже были свидетелями подобной истории не так давно.

Другой момент в том, что нельзя требовать от модератора проявлять активность именно в разруливании общественных драм общественным же путём (не в модераторском закрытом чате), а хотя бы на Мете или в общем чате. Конечно, кандидат может написать нечто подобное в своей избирательной речи, и ему, наверное, поверят и те, кому это важно, проголосуют за него. Но потом всё может пойти так, как описано параграфом выше. Поэтому ...

... наиболее подходящим решением и смелым шагом я бы хотел увидеть здесь именно Ваше, @VladD, желание баллотироваться на пост модератора. К тому же и правило про отсутствие нахождения в бане за последний год отменять не надо. Ваша активность и на Мете, и в чате (про основной сайт вовсе можно не говорить) позволяет надеяться, что наличие ромба рядом с Вашим именем сделает ruSO только лучше и может быть даже вернёт на сайт хотя бы некоторых активных участников, которые решили сократить своё присутствие на сайте в свете последних драм.

Comment: Кролика и AK в модераторы!

Comment: @Suvitruf Представил картину "кролик с АК" :)

Comment: +1 за первую часть, и -2 за вторую. Итого -1.

Comment: @Kromster -2 за Кролика? )

Comment: @Suvitruf ответ начался с объективных вещей: выборы не гарантия "правильного" выбора сообщества; ромб не делает его носителя неприкасаемым. И т.д. Но увод темы в сторону (похвалы в сторону ТС и надежда что это сократит драму, а не усилит ее) мне показался неправильным.

Comment: @Kromster ух, неправильное мнение? Текст про Кролика как раз и подчёркивает ситуацию)

Comment: @Kromster никакого увода в сторону, просто ТС - это максимально сильный вариант кандидата для решения проблем, которые озвучены ТС же. То есть если и это не прокатит, то надеяться больше не на что.

Comment: @Suvitruf увод темы в сторону мне показался неправильным. Вот такое у меня мнение. Текст про кролика подчеркивает лишь то, что вопрос задан про довыборы, а имеет в виду "хотим своего человека в модераторах чтобы .. было больше драмы?"

Comment: @alexolut А зачем кролика в модераторы? Для что? Банить он не будет, разгребать очереди можно и не будучи модератором, воздействовать силой слов и аргументов можно и без модераторских привилегий, с тревогами текущий состав и так справляется (может что-то упустил?).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ромб, полученный на свободных демократических выборах отражает доверие сообщества к участнику. Это как и репа, показатель статуса и веса в сообществе. Вместе они должны дать убойный эффект, особенно при активном участии в разрешении драм на Мете и в чате. И я был бы не прочь это проверить.

Comment: @alexolut Наличие статуса не мешает мне и другим людям относиться к любому человеку настороженно или совсем негативно. Если наличие статуса президента не мешает мне его презирать (ну и что, что кто-то за него голосовал и верил его пустым словам и "благим" намереньям), то что говорить про модераторов?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov странно как-то из настороженного отношения появилось презрение. Как будто президент (или модератор) не человек. Но, суть не в этом, суть в том, что статус, не смотря на Ваше высказывание, имеет значение. Будь то статус президента или модератора.

Comment: @alexolut Я имел ввиду градацию негативного отношения (от настороженного отношения до презрения). "Статус имеет значение" — Какое значение? Значение для какой цели?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov об этом я уже сказал выше, это признак доверия сообщества, пусть и некоторой его части, но заведомо большей, чем у других (не прошедших) кандидатов. Мы же не будем тут говорить о махинациях на выборах модераторов? :)

Comment: @alexolut Этот "признак" не помешал ТС записывать модераторов либо в "равнодушных", либо в "псов режима", я несколько утрирую, но плюс-минус это, как я понимаю, его текущая позиция. Чего реально стоит этот признак? Что мешает другим игнорировать этот признак?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov в кавычках это цитаты? Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылки в таком случае.

Comment: @alexolut Это не цитаты, это вольная передача его позиции. Собственно этот вопрос тоже из этой серии, что нет модератора от народа, все текущие в сговоре со злой и жестокой администрацией. Это всё тоже моя **вольная интерпретация** этого вопроса и недавних фраз из чата, из неё я сложил у себя в голове такую картинку. Как вы считаете, я сильно далёк от истины?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov истина где-то там. Мы же только можем иметь и поддерживать те или иные позиции. То есть иметь личную видимость ситуации. Например, моя видимость больше совпадает с позицией VladD, чем Ваша.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Я бы был признателен, если бы вы не интерпретировали мою позицию, особенно искажая её при этом. Нет, ваша «вольная интерпретация» не совпадает с моей позицией.