# Отсутствие переводов для всплывающего сообщения о дубликате

Tags: дефект, локализация, дубликаты

При одобрении от ТС дубликата вылезло такое уведомление, но как можно увидеть из картинки ниже с переводами есть проблемка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неправильные метки выбираете. Я заменю на нужные, но примите к сведению. Обратите внимание на описание меток.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, принял к сведению, просто обсуждение мне кажется всегда уместным так как обсуждаем ведь проблему по или вопрос по факту, а вот с дефектом я как-то не всегда применяю его, так как там пишется в описании что уведомление разработчиков сайта, а здесь ведь не с разработкой связано а с просто переводом, или это тоже подразумевает задействование разрабов? ведь насколько я знаю нужно будет просто в тул добавить строки и все?

Comment: Так уж сложилось, что дефекты сайта (в части локализации) могут правиться из без участия SOтрудников. Но метка всё же должна быть [meta-tag:дефект]. Может быть стоит несколько дополнить её описание, кстати. Но здесь могут тем не менее всплывать ситуации, когда строка не доступна для перевода вовсе, или перевод не подхватывается по какой-то причине. Это уже однозначно к SOтрудникам. Но заранее это не всегда понятно.

Comment: я понял, учту в будущих вопросах) спасибо за замечание :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13670

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.4.1.38970

Comment: У меня складывается впечатление, что весь сайт переведен вами (да так оно и получаается, большая часть — ваша). Большое спасибо вам за труд!

Comment: @VictorVosMottor любой участник может предложить свой перевод на [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/), но так получилось, что у меня ещё есть [право на утверждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/176217), поэтому грех им не воспользоваться. Хотя у модераторов тоже есть такая возможность. Полный список [здесь](https://ru.traducir.win/users) по роли Reviewer.