# Проблема с переводом причины изменения репутации (отклонение утвержденной правки) во вкладке репутация

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Наблюдается проблема с переводом *reverted* и *suggested edit approval overridden* [во вкладке репутация в профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236980/drakonoved?tab=reputation) (см. за сегодня, 26.02.2018):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

предлагаемый понятный перевод:

***reverted*** - *откат*.

***suggested edit approval overridden*** - *предлагаемая утвержденная правка отклонена*

**UPD:** в данном случае был откат автором вопроса утвержденной правки, поэтому изменен перевод.

Comment: @Nofate что-то скорости уже не те...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Краткий текст оставил как предложено, а описание перевёл так:

- утверждённая правка аннулирована

На сайте - после обновления базы и пересборки движка.

Comment: *после обновления базы и пересборки движка* - а когда это случится ?

Comment: @Alex краткий ответ есть в ветке другого бага от Вас. Более полный [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6484/176217).